# How do I use Postgresql's COPY command to import a file with consecutive single quotes?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to import a TSV file into Postgresql. I have created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE description (
    id TEXT
    , effective_time DATE
    , active INT
    , module_id TEXT
    , concept_id TEXT
    , language_code TEXT
    , type_id TEXT
    , term TEXT
    , case_significance_id TEXT
);
```

I have a TSV file like so:

```
    id      effectiveTime   active  moduleId        conceptId       languageCode    typeId  term    caseSignificanceId
    12118017        20170731        1       900000000000207008      6708002 en      900000000000013009      Intrauterine cordocentesis      900000000000448009
    12119013        20020131        1       900000000000207008      6709005 en      900000000000013009      Gentamicin 2''-nucleotidyltransferase   900000000000020002
    12119013        20170731        1       900000000000207008      6709005 en      900000000000013009      Gentamicin 2''-nucleotidyltransferase   900000000000448009
    12120019        20020131        1       900000000000207008      6710000 en      900000000000013009      Nitric oxide    900000000000020002
```

Note that the middle two entries have two consecutive single quotes acting as the symbol for double-prime (`Gentamicin 2''-nucleotidyltransferase`).

If I run

```
psql=# \copy description FROM /path/to/foo.txt WITH DELIMITER AS E'\t';
```

I get `ERROR:  missing data for column "effective_time"`. I think that's because the `''` is screwing up the parsing of the column boundaries.

I have tried finding and replacing the `''` instances with either `\'\'` or `''''` and using `CSV QUOTE E'\''` or `CSV QUOTE ''''`, respectively, but I get the same error.

How do I edit the file or alter the `\copy` command to import the file correctly?

Comment: I copied the example data that you pasted into a text editor to examine it. There are spaces instead of tabs in the what you pasted. If I replace all the separator-spaces with tabs, then the copy command works fine.

Comment: You are right. The documentation suggested this was a TSV and it looked like one, but I never verified that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haleemur Ali correctly points out that the original file—whose README purports it to comprise "UTF-8 encoded tab-delimited flat files which can be imported into any database"—is in fact *not* tab-separated, which may be my editor's fault. It works once I fix that.